# Webform-CiviCRM recurring contributions Error?

Tags: webform-civicrm

When submitting a recurring contribution on a Webform, If I select recurring for 12 months (for example), Instead of the total amount being charged and scheduled for every month. The form divides my total amount by 12 and charges 1/12 of the amount every month. 
Then in Civi it records the total amount as 1/12 of the total amount but the non-deductible amount remains the actual total amount.
See screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ad 1) installments: that’s not an error - that’s a feature! It allows you to extend the concept of recurring contributions to eg paying for an Event in installments (day care centre fees eg - $4000 -> paid in 10 installments - monthly - $400/mo recurring contribution.

Ad 2) non_deductible amount - I remember fixing that - will have to check if that bug has resurfaced.

PS - If you’re looking for a classic start recurring series -> open-ended you can set installments = 0 (as per CiviCRM convention) - then the amount shown will be transacted monthly as is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking a simple Radio Button option "Recurring Yes/No"

[image]

Here are the steps to do that *but you will loose the ability to auto-terminate the recurring contribution after X months*.

1. In the webform field for the Civi Installment, in Edit>Properties
   a. add a 1 to the Key  b. remove the Default 1
2. Create a new webform field that is Radio select
3. In the new field Key, paste the original Key (without the added 1 from the civi Installment field that you just edited).
4. In Options, just have Yes & No and below that you check "Customize Keys" Set Yes = 0 No = 1
5. Test leaving the original Civi Installment blank
6. If you have a successful recurring donation created, then delete the original Civi Installment field from your form.